# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject

Tags: java, gwt

I have an app that use GWT version 2.8.0-beta1 and run it through `mvn gwt:run`

The problem is that it throws this error:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  ... 19 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject from [Module "deployment.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules-1.3.3.Final.jar:1.3.3.Final]
[INFO]  ... 23 more
```

Even there's the `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.json.JSON'/>` in the `gwt.xml` file of the app.

What is the root cause of `ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Dumb guess:  you have https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0 added to your classpath?

Comment: Have you referenced gwt.json in the server-side code?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin my app is pure Javascript app when compile it connects to backend through RequestBuilder only so there is no server-side code at all.

Comment: (1) So why JBoss is trying to find and load this class? (2) Backend is server-side, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject is a class from gwt-user.jar. If you want to make this class available at serverside then include this jar in your runtime classpath.